# How to pass a regsiterComponent to graphql using typescript interface?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have this Comp and I want to pass it to the graphql of react-apollo:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, ChildMutateProps } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
interface Props {
    children :(
        data:{ submit: (values:any) => Promise<null> }
    ) => JSX.Element | null
}
export class Comp extends React.PureComponent<ChildMutateProps<Props, any, any>> {
    submit = async ( values: any ) => {
        const response = await this.props.mutate({ variables: values })
        console.log( "response: ", response )
        return null
    }

    render() {
        return this.props.children({ submit: this.submit })
    }
}
const registerMutation = gql`
    mutation RegisterMutation( $email: String!, $password: String! ) {
        register( email: $email, password: $password ) {
            path
            message
        }
    }
`
export const RegisterController = graphql <Props> ( registerMutation ) ( Comp )
```

I get  this typescript err from Comp when it is passed to the graphql in the last line :

```
class Comp
Argument of type 'typeof Comp' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Props & Partial<DataProps<{}, {}>> & Partial<MutateProps<{}, {}>>>'.
  Type 'typeof Comp' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Props & Partial<DataProps<{}, {}>> & Partial<MutateProps<{}, {}>>, any>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'Props & Partial<DataProps<{}, {}>> & Partial<MutateProps<{}, {}>>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<ChildMutateProps<Props, any, any>>'.
        Types of property 'mutate' are incompatible.
          Type 'MutationFunction<{}, {}> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MutationFunction<any, any>'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MutationFunction<any, any>'.ts(2345)
Peek Problem
No quick fixes available
```

I`m familiar with generics but when it comes to nested ones looks to be confusing to make the component happy...

this is the graphql interface:

```
(alias) graphql<Props, {}, {}, Partial<DataProps<{}, {}>> & Partial<MutateProps<{}, {}>>>(document: DocumentNode, operationOptions?: OperationOption<Props, {}, {}, Partial<DataProps<{}, {}>> & Partial<MutateProps<{}, {}>>> | undefined): (WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<...>) => React.ComponentClass<...>
import graphql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComponentType<TProps & TChildProps>` shows `TProps` that is the first props that grqphql takes is passed to Comp, so graphql first props should be same as Comp props. as a resault the last line would be :

```
export const RegisterController = graphql <ChildMutateProps<Props, any, any>> ( registerMutation ) ( Comp )
```

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and did the next tutorial with generating the code as well, this is how the working solution looks like, GraphQL has changed its params.

```
// types
interface ComponentProps {
  children: (data: {
    submit: (values: any) => Promise<null>;
  }) => JSX.Element | null;
}

type WithMutateProps = ChildMutateProps<
  ComponentProps,
  RegisterMutation,
  RegisterMutationVariables
>;

// class definition
export class C extends React.PureComponent<WithMutateProps> { ...

// final controller
export const RegisterController = graphql<
  ComponentProps,
  RegisterMutation,
  RegisterMutationVariables,
  WithMutateProps
>(registerMutation)(C);
```